# How to write unit test for this particular function in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, download, mocking, patch

There's a function `result = Downloader.downloadFiles(list_to_download, download_path, username, password)` in the file `downloadModule`, which will return a boolean(True/False) to the 'result' variable. How to write a mock to this call such that `result` will always return True. Tried the following way but got the following error `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rsplit'`.

```
@patch(downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles)
def test_download_files(self,mock_download_files):
        mock_download_files.return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles(),True)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Missing quotes

I think you have only to add the quotes (`'`) as delimiter for the patch parameter `downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles`.

Your code becomes the following:

```py
@patch('downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles')
def test_download_files(self,mock_download_files):
        mock_download_files.return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles(),True)
```

### The complete test file

Below I show the test file where is present the statement:

```
import downloadModule
```

which import the module `downloadModule`. The following is the complete test file that I've used on my system:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import downloadModule

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles')
    def test_download_files(self, mock_download_files):
        mock_download_files.return_value = True
        self.assertEqual(downloadModule.Downloader.downloadFiles(), True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```